# Embed VLC Player 1.1.7 in page for IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, embed, vlc

I am looking for a code sample on how to place a `VLC player` (latest version) on a web page and have it play a movie file.  `Pure HTML/Javascript`.

Target Browser is `IE 8++` for this.

The latest `VLC` documentation, states that there is a new universal `Javascript API`, but the examples use `EMBED` tags... I have searched high and low and can't find a working code snippet for IE.

Documentation:

[http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aWebPlugin)

Comment: Word of advice: Not all of your users will have VLC installed. Aim for media player or quicktime files because that will target the largest amount of users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using another type of player?

I have used [jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12538/supported-player-embed-methods#jwembedder) and it is great: